# Is gluLookAt together with glFrustum distorting the rendering?

Tags: opengl, perspective, perspectivecamera

I am wondering if `gluLookAt` together with `glFrustum` is distorting the rendered picture.

This is how a scene is rendered:

[image]

And here's the code that rendered it.

`InitCamera` is called *once* and should, as I understand it now, set up a matrix so as if I looked from a position 2 units above and 3 units in front of the origin towards the origin. Also `glFrustum` is used in order to create a perspective`.

```
void InitCamera() {

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();

  gluLookAt (
    0,  2  ,   3, 
    0,  0  ,   0,
    0,  1  , - 0 
  );

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glFrustum   (-  1,     1, 
               -  1,     1, 
                  1,1000.0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Then `TheScene` is what actually draws the picture:

```
void TheScene() {

  glClear(
    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | 
    GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT    
  );

  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

  // Draw red circle around origin and radius 2 units:    
  glColor3d(1,0,0);
  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
  for (double i = 0; i<=2 * M_PI; i+=M_PI / 20.0) {
    glVertex3d(std::sin(i) * 2.0, 0, std::cos(i) * 2.0);
  }
  glEnd();

  // draw green sphere at origin:
  glColor3d(0,1,0);
  glutSolidSphere(0.2,128, 128);


  // draw pink sphere a bit away    
  glPushMatrix();
    glColor3d(1,0,1);
    glTranslated(8, 3, -10);
    glutSolidSphere(0.8, 128, 128);
  glPopMatrix();

  SwapBuffers(hDC_opengl);
}
```

The red *ball* should be drawn in the origin and at the center of the red circle around it. But looking at it just feels wierd, and gives me the imprssion that the green ball is not in the center at all.

Also, the pink ball should, imho, be drawn as a perfect circle, not as an ellipse.

So, am I wrong, and the picture is drawn correctly, or am I setting up something wrong?

Comment: It could just be the viewing direction. Check the scene from another viewpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expectations are simply wrong

- The perspective projection of a 3d circle (if the circle is fully visible) is an ellipse, however the projection of the center of the circle is NOT in general the center of the ellipse.
  [image: Perspective distortion on centers]
- The outline of the perspective projection of a sphere is in general a [conic section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) i.e. can be a circle, an ellipse, a parabola or an hyperbola depending on the position of viewpoint, projection plane and sphere in 3D. The reason is that the outline of the sphere can be imagined as a cone starting from the viewpoint and touching the sphere being intersected with the projection plane.

Of course if you're looking at a circle with a perfectly perpendicular camera the center of the circle will be projected to the center of the circle projection. In the same manner if your camera is pointing exactly to a sphere the sphere outline will be a circle, but those are special cases, not the general case.

These differences between the centers are more evident with strong perspective (wide angle) cameras. With a [parallel projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_projection) instead this apparent distortion is absent (i.e. the projection of the center of a circle is exactly the center of the projection of the circle).

Comment: Yes, what you write is clear. But your picture doesn't feel weird, mine does. When I wrote that the green spot should be in the center I didn't mean that to be interpreted as should be geometrically be drawn in the center but as should look like it was in the center.

Comment: The problem is the same one, to make it more evident I've updated the picture using a wider angle camera and I also added a partially visible sphere. Of course the stronger the perspective of the camera is and the bigger is the difference between centers. With a parallel projection the effect is absent (i.e. the projection of the center of a circle is exactly the center of the projection of a circle).

Comment: For a sanity test, add code to render some axes and grid lines. Then you can visualize for sure how your stuff is being projected.

Comment: You're probably right. I first couldn't believe it. My camera's viewing angle was far too wide.

Answer (score 1):

To see the green sphere in the centre of the screen with a perfect circle around it you need to change the camera location like so:

```
gluLookAt (
  0, 3, 0, 
  0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1 
);
```

Not sure what's causing the distortion of the purple sphere though.

Answer (score 1):

The perspective is correct, it just looks distorted because that's how things fell together here.
try this for gluLookAt, and play around a bit more.:

```
gluLookAt (
    0,  2  ,   10, 
    0,  0  ,   0,
    0,  1  ,   0 
  );
```

The way I tried it out was with a setup that allows me to adjust the position and view direction with the mouse, so you get real time motion. Your scene looks fine when I move around. If you want I can get you the complete code so you can do that too, but it's a bit more than I want to shove into an answer here.